# Jupyter autoreload not working with pycharm

Tags: ipython, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I am editing my project with pycharm, and I want to show final results (Charts, mcmc results) on a Jupyter Notebook. As I don't like Pycharm's notebook options (They are still not mature enough IMO) I use the browser version.
I import my project as a module and use:

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Now, when working solely on pycharm, it works fine. When editing files with sublime and running Jupyter, also fine.
But when Pycharm is open, and I'm trying autoreload, it doesn't work.
Are there maybe contradictions in the kernels? Or maybe the pycharm doesn't really hard-save (I'm guessing) the files?

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably too late, but you should put your *.ipynb under your Pycharm project path, then the auto-reload magically works fine